# When attempting to call a Coinbase API Endpoint, I am getting an "invalid signature" error

Tags: java, coinbase-api

I am currently attempting to build a personal application that trades for me using the Coinbase API. However, I am running into the same error every time I attempt to make a call to endpoint that requires authentication, "invalid signature."

I am only making this post here because I have scoured the internet (stackoverflow included) trying nearly every solution, and none have worked. My running hypothesis is that the HmacSHA256 method I am using is not correct, but I have tried many, only for none to work. I make this assumption because the arguments to my HmacSHA256 method are:

`String secretKey, String timestamp, String method, String requestPath, String body`

The prehash string is timestamp + method + requestPath + body and uses the secret key on the prehash string.

I have verified my secret key is correct (even creating a new API Key to ensure this), verified my timestamp is correct, as it will not check the header if it is incorrect (tested by creating a false timestamp, that error was caught first each time), the method is a simple "GET", and I'm not entirely sure about my request path. I'm attempting to call https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts, and I assume "/v2/accounts" is the request path. Body is optional for GET requests.

Here's where I'm creating my header:

```
    public static JSONObject getAccountData() {
        String url = requests.getJSONObject("wallet_data").getString("requestPath");
        String requestPath = "/v2/accounts";
        String accessKey = credentials.getJSONObject("standard").getString("key");
        String secretKey = credentials.getJSONObject("standard").getString("secret");
        String method = "GET";
        String timestamp = getEpochTime();
        String body = "";
        String header = HeaderGenerator.getHMACHeader(secretKey, timestamp, method, requestPath, body);


        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .addHeader(CB_ACCESS_KEY, accessKey)
                .addHeader(CB_ACCESS_SIGN, header)
                .addHeader(CB_ACCESS_TIMESTAMP, timestamp)
                .addHeader(CB_VERSION, getDate())
                .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                .url(url)
                .build();

        String show = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < request.headers().size(); i++) {
            show += (request.headers().name(i) + ": " + request.headers().get(request.headers().name(i)));
            show+= "\n";
        }
        System.out.println(show);
        Response res;
        JSONObject par = null;
        try {
            res = APICommunicator.sendRequest(request);
            par = new JSONObject(res);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            ErrorLogger.logException(e);
        }
        return par;
    }
```

and for the HmacSHA256 method:

```
    public static String getHMACHeader(String secretKey, String timestamp, String method, String requestPath, String body) {
        String prehash = timestamp + method.toUpperCase() + requestPath;

        if(method.equals("POST") || method.equals("PUT")) {
            prehash += body;
        }

         byte[] secretDecoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(secretKey);
         SecretKey keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(secretDecoded, "HmacSHA256");
         Mac sha256 = null;
        try {
            sha256 = (Mac) Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
            sha256.init(keyspec);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(sha256.doFinal(prehash.getBytes()));
    }
```

Again, I have ensured my API Key and Secret Key are correct and enabled.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution!

Many of the guides I was using were utilizing Coinbase Pro's API, which uses a Base64 encoding scheme. In  Normal Coinbase, the encoding should be Hex.

Here is my updated `getHMacHeader` method:

```
    public static String getHMACHeader(String secretKey, String timestamp, String method, String requestPath, String body) {
        String prehash = timestamp + method.toUpperCase() + requestPath;

        if(method.equals("POST") || method.equals("PUT")) {
            prehash += body;
        }

         SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
         Mac sha256 = null;
        try {
            sha256 = (Mac) Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
            sha256.init(keyspec);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String hash = Hex.encodeHexString((sha256.doFinal(prehash.getBytes())));

        return hash;
    }
```